# (PHP) Different values for different value in html form

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, message, contact-form

I have a contact form with two radio buttons. But I need to show messages to the client according with the chosen radio button.
I will try to explain better:
If the client choose the YES radio button and press submit, it will appear a message "Great! I see you there!" and I will receive an email with the chosen option.The same with the NO radio button, but it will appear a "C'mon..." as message.

Here is the php I have:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $remetente = "email@domain.com"; 
    $destinatario = "email@domain.com";
    $assunto = "Subject";
    $data = date("d/m/y");
    $hora = date("H:i");
    $charset = $_POST['charset'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    //This is the radio button value that i want to put conditionals.
    $rsvp = $_POST['rsvp'];
    $navegador = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $corpo = utf8_decode("Data: ".$data."<br />Hora: ".$hora."<br />Nome: ".$nome."<br />E-mail: ".$email."<br />Ip: ".$ip."<br />Browser: ".$navegador."<br />RSVP: ".$rsvp."\r\n");

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=".$charset."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$remetente."\r\n";

    $headers .= "From: ".$remetente."\r\n";


    //This is the part that i think it has to be changed.
    if(mail($destinatario, $assunto, $corpo, $headers)) {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=message_sended.php/>';
    } else {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=error.php/>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=error.php/>';
}
?>
```

I have tried this, but is not working:

```
    if(mail($destinatario, $assunto, $corpo, $headers) ) {
        if($rsvp = 'YES'){
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=message_sended_YES.php/>';
        } else {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=error.php/>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=error.php/>';
    }

    if($rsvp = 'NO'){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=message_sended.php_NO/>';
    } else {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=error.php/>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=error.php/>';
}
```

Then I did this:

```
if(mail($destinatario, $assunto, $corpo, $headers)) {
    if($rsvp == 'sim'){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=sim.php>';
    } 
    else
    {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=contato_mensagem_erro.php>';
    }
}   
else 
{
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=contato_mensagem_erro.php>';
}

if($rsvp == 'nao'){
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=nao.php>';
} 
else
{
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=contato_mensagem_erro.php>';
}
}   
else 
{
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=0;url=contato_mensagem_erro.php>';
}
```

Is not working. Actually, when the user chose the "no" radio button he receive the right message, but when he chose the "yes" radio button he receive the wrong message (the error message) but i receive the the form email normally...

**Edit**
Ok! It works!
Here is how I did:

```
if(mail($destinatario, $assunto, $corpo, $headers)) {

if($rsvp == "sim"){

   echo 

     header('Location: sim.php/');

} 

else

{

   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=0;url=contato_mensagem_erro.php>";

}

}   

else 

{

   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=0;url=contato_mensagem_erro.php>";

}

if($rsvp == "nao"){

   echo header('Location: nao.php/');

} 

else

{

   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=0;url=contato_mensagem_erro.php>";

}

}   

else 

{

   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=0;url=contato_mensagem_erro.php>";

}
```

I really don't know if it's coded right, but it's working...

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? The above code throws a Syntax Error. What happens if you fix that first?

Comment: No sintax error when I type it In Dreamweaver.

Comment: the code has been edited/fixed in the meantime ;)

Comment: I saw what you mean by sintax error. Is the messages file names, right? I just changed the names to put in here and I mess up with the extention names when i was typing here. The original files names is in portuguese.

Comment: No - The above code has been edited by AJ...  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6669722/revisions In the beginning when I looked up this thread - the code threw a Syntax Error. Check out the answer by George Cummins - it will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Oh! Thak you! Im new in stackoverflow... 
I have edited the original question based in the George's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lines will lead to unexpected results:

```
if($rsvp = 'YES'){
if($rsvp = 'NO'){
```

This method will simply set the value of `$rsvp` to 'YES' and 'NO' respectively. To test for equivalence, you should use the comparison operator `==`:

```
if($rsvp == 'YES'){
```

and

```
if($rsvp == 'NO'){
```

Comment: Gerorge, thank you for you answer! Can you please take a look in my edit in the original question?

Comment: @ÉrNica: I edited your newly-posted code to insert indentation. This revealed the issue: There are stray, unmatched braces in your code. Can you work on the indentation and bracketing to make sure your if/else statements work as you expect?

Comment: Yes, we can! :D
Thank you George!
I will post the results.

Comment: Thank you! I have posted the working code. I dont know if I did it right, but its wonking!

Comment: @ÉrNica: Congratulations! I will look forward to your questions in the future if you need further assistance. Enjoy!